# Is there a way to guarantee a callback beyond the callback method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

First, I must apologize for the code atrocity you are about to see.

I am writing a SOAP web service in NodeJS using the [SOAP module](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

My question is: Is there a way to execute code after multiple asynchronous methods have completed?

My code is the following

```
var http = require('http');
var soap = require('soap');

var strategyService = {
  Strategy_Service: {
    Strategy_Port: {
      getOptions: function(args, callback) {
        var source = "";
        var destination = "";
        var taxi = false;
        var shuttle = false;
        var bus = false;
        var taxiResponse = "N/A";
        var shuttleResponse = "N/A";
        var busResponse = "N/A";

        if (args.source.$value != undefined){
          source = args.source.$value;
          destination = args.destination.$value;
          taxi = getBoolean(args.taxi.$value);
          shuttle = getBoolean(args.shuttle.$value);
          bus = getBoolean(args.bus.$value);
        } else {
          source = args.source;
          destination = args.destination;
          taxi = getBoolean(args.taxi);
          shuttle = getBoolean(args.shuttle);
          bus = getBoolean(args.bus);
        }

        var url;
        var args = {"tns:source":source, "tns:destination":destination};

        if (taxi){
          url = "http://localhost:8001/wsdl?wsdl";
          soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
            client.Taxi_Service.Taxi_Port.takeTaxi(args, function(err, result){
              if (err) throw err;
              taxiResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
              if (!bus && ! shuttle){
                callback({
                  taxi: taxiResponse,
                  bus: busResponse,
                  shuttle: shuttleResponse
                });
              }
              if (bus){
                url = "http://localhost:8003/wsdl?wsdl";
                soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
                  client.Bus_Service.Bus_Port.takeBus(args, function(err, result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    busResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
                    if (!shuttle){
                      callback({
                        taxi: taxiResponse,
                        bus: busResponse,
                        shuttle: shuttleResponse
                      });
                    }
                    if (shuttle){
                      url = "http://localhost:8002/wsdl?wsdl";
                      soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
                        client.Shuttle_Service.Shuttle_Port.takeShuttle(args, function(err, result){
                          if (err) throw err;
                          shuttleResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
                          callback({
                            taxi: taxiResponse,
                            bus: busResponse,
                            shuttle: shuttleResponse
                          });
                        })
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })
              } else if (shuttle){
                url = "http://localhost:8002/wsdl?wsdl";
                soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
                  client.Shuttle_Service.Shuttle_Port.takeShuttle(args, function(err, result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    shuttleResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
                    callback({
                      taxi: taxiResponse,
                      bus: busResponse,
                      shuttle: shuttleResponse
                    });
                  });
                });
              }
            });
          });
        } else if (bus){
          url = "http://localhost:8003/wsdl?wsdl";
          soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
            client.Bus_Service.Bus_Port.takeBus(args, function(err, result){
              if (err) throw err;
              busResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
              if (!shuttle){
                callback({
                  taxi: taxiResponse,
                  bus: busResponse,
                  shuttle: shuttleResponse
                });
              }
              if (shuttle){
                url = "http://localhost:8002/wsdl?wsdl";
                soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
                  client.Shuttle_Service.Shuttle_Port.takeShuttle(args, function(err, result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    shuttleResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
                    callback({
                      taxi: taxiResponse,
                      bus: busResponse,
                      shuttle: shuttleResponse
                    });
                  })
                })
              }
            });
          });
        } else if (shuttle){
          url = "http://localhost:8002/wsdl?wsdl";
          soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
            client.Shuttle_Service.Shuttle_Port.takeShuttle(args, function(err, result){
              if (err) throw err;
              shuttleResponse = result.message.substring(0, result.message.length);
              callback({
                taxi: taxiResponse,
                bus: busResponse,
                shuttle: shuttleResponse
              });
            });
          });
        } else {
          callback({
            taxi: taxiResponse,
            bus: busResponse,
            shuttle: shuttleResponse
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('StrategyService.wsdl', 'utf8'),
      server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
          response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
      });
server.listen(8000);
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', strategyService, xml);

getBoolean = function(string){
  lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
  if (lowerCase == "true" || lowerCase == "t" || lowerCase == "1"){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In my defense, I will say that this is my first attempt at creating a SOAP service using NodeJS, and I am fairly new to NodeJS as well.

### A brief explanation of what I've done

The first if else block is because I use SoapUI as well as NodeJS to test my server, and they seem to pass the data in different ways.

Then, the disgusting beast of nested if else blocks. This is because the callback method is executed at the end of an asynchronous function, but there seems to be no way (that I'm aware of) to execute a function with the condition that multiple asynchronous functions have given a response.

### What I've tried

I first tried to set a variable in the callback of the different methods. For instance

```
fun1(args, callback){
  fun1Finished = true;
  callback();
}

fun2(args, callback){
  fun2Finished = true;
  callback();
}

while (!fun1Finished || !fun2Finished){
  // code gets stuck here until fun1 and fun2 are finished
}

fun3(args, callback){
  // do stuff that requires both functions to be finished
  callback();
}
```

That didn't work, so then I decided to write a series of nested callbacks such as

```
fun1(args, callback){
  // do stuff
  callback(
    // now fun2 will be executed after fun1
    fun2(args, callback){
      // do more stuff
      callback(
        // now fun3 will be executed after fun2, which was executed after fun1
        fun3(args, callback){
          // do stuff that requires both fun1 and fun2 to be finished
          callback();
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

That code does indeed work, but it's uglier than all get out, and I hate it.

Any suggestions are much appreciated, and code examples help me more than anything.

If you are interested in looking at all the project files, you can view them [on my github](https://github.com/electr0sheep/Strategy-Web-Services).

Comment: The answer to async callback hell is promises.

Comment: The non-promise answer to waiting on multiple callbacks is counting how many are still active. Increment count as each launches; in callback, decrement, and trigger final computation if zero. (Or, equivalently but more powerfully, use array of active xhr, push when starting, pop in callback, process when empty.) But you totally should learn promises, as they do all the wonky stuff for you. For example, [soap-as-promised](https://github.com/warseph/soap-as-promised) with [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)'s [`all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html).

Comment: I wanted to add that I've found a pretty good introduction to javascript promises in the [atom plugin tutorial](https://github.com/blog/2231-building-your-first-atom-plugin). It even references [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), and as it just so happens, it looks exactly like my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible! : )

You need a control flow library. Something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md) for a callback version, or a promise library, like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) or Q (or even ES6 promises).

If using async, you'd line up all the functions you want to run, and then wait for them all to happen either in [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#parallel) or in [series](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#seriestasks-callback) (or in a special series called a [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#waterfall) if you need results to trickle down).

Promises are a little different, but have similar functionality.